# Why I cannot access self in this particular method but am allowed in others?

Tags: swift

I have seen this question on SO but the answers there appear to be talking about functions that return `self`.

I am creating a class extension that starts like this

```
extension Sequence where Element: Comparable {

  func normalize() -> [Element] {
     let count = self.count 

  }

}
```

I need to get the number of elements `self.count` and in subsequent lines use the array elements, like `self[i]` but Swift complains saying that `self` nas no member called `count` and will not let me use `self` in any context.

How do I do that?

Comment: `Sequence` doesn't have a `count`, you probably want `Collection`

Comment: Changed to collection. Self.count works but I still cannot access the elements.

Comment: @MLL If you're trying to use the subscript operator, you'll need the `RandomAccessCollection`. Although it would be better to rewrite your code not to need it. Just a guess (just from the name `normalize`), but I suspect that you can implement your function as a single call to `Sequence.map`, without needing `count` or the subscript operator.

Comment: @Alexander unfortunately in this case I need to access self because this extension I am trying to write will use `vDSP` Accelerate functions.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the problem. There's no issue calling `self`. There's an issue with accessing properties or calling methods that don't exist on `self`. Generalizing code by accepting more and more general types is a double edged sword. More types become compatible with your code, but they do less and less. For example, `Sequence` is an awesome place for implementing `map`, `map` doesn't need a count, random indexing, mutability of the collection, etc. All it needs is iterability, and `Sequence` is all about something that can be iterated.

Comment: @MLL In your case, if you're looking to wrap `vDSP_normalize(D)`, you need a type who can provide the arguments that `vDSP_normalize(D)` expects. You need a type that can provide a `UnsafePointer<Float>` to a buffer of elements. `Sequence` can't do that, only `Array`, `UnsafeBufferPointer`, `UnsafePointer`, and a few other types can.

Comment: If you have some test data that I can play with, I can take a stab at implementing this wrapper

Answer (score 0):

In swift, the `count` property is not defined in `Sequence`, but in `Collection`, so you need to extend from `Collection` instead.

```
extension Collection where Element: Comparable {
    func normalize() -> [Element] {
        let count = self.count

    }
}
```

If you also need to access a value of the collection by indexes (`self[i]`), you should extend `RandomAccessCollection` instead, which provide both `count` (because a random access collection is a collection) and `subscript` function.

```
extension RandomAccessCollection where Element: Comparable {
    func normalize() -> [Element] {
        let count = self.count

        let first = self[startIndex]
        let second = self[index(startIndex, offsetBy: 1)]

        return [first, second]
    }
}
```

*Note: As `RandomAccessCollection` indexes are not necessarily an int, you must use the `index(_:offsetBy:)` function to create an index that can be passed in the subscript method.*